# SQL query results in ODBC --Call Failed

Tags: sql, odbc, ms-access-2007, outer-join

I'm having a bit of a Newbie problem (I think) with a query I am trying to develop. We have a SQL server database that imports data from a separate systems log files. These files are broken up over a number of tables in the SQL database. I apologise for this being a bit long-winded but hopefully it clearly explains where I'm running into problems.

Due to my current corporate restrictions I'm limited to using an MS Access 2007 or Excel 2007 front end to query and analyse the data that has been extracted from the log files.

I've been working on a query that is supposed to get all of the records from one table (containing check messages) and some corresponding data from second table (General Information if it exists) based on the a UnitID.

So - using a simple select statement for one of the unit ID's I get 51,319 records returned. This is the number of records that should be returned (the results will go into some charts to look for patterns in the messages).

```
    SELECT
      Messages.Timestamp,
      Messages.UnitID,
      Messages.Stuff
    FROM
      Messages
    WHERE
      Messages.UnitID = '4400'
    ORDER BY
      Messages.Timestamp
```

If I change this to SELECT DISTINCT I get 38,024 records. Ultimately, I don't want this as I need all of them but this comes into play in a little while - so bear with me.

When I try to join these results with the General Information table the query fails - ODBC --Call Failed

```
    SELECT
      Messages.TimeStamp,
      Messages.UnitID,
      Messages.Stuff,
      GeneralInfo.MoreStuff
    FROM
      Messages LEFT OUTER JOIN GeneralInfo 
        ON Messages.TimeStamp = GeneralInfo.TimeStamp 
        AND Messages.UnitID = GeneralInfo.UnitID
    WHERE
      Messages.UnitID = '4400'
    ORDER BY
      Messages.TimeStamp
```

Out of morbid curiosity I changed this to a SELECT DISTINCT and it works - returning 40,810 records.

What could be causing my ODBC fail (I suspect returning too many records)? 
If my suspicion is correct, why would the joined query be returning more records that the simple SELECT query I started with?

Thanks In Advance
Jason

Comment: How long does the failing query take before failing? is it a timeout issue?

Comment: Do you get any error message from the ODBC driver?

Comment: christiandev - The query takes approximately 2 minutes to fail, so it could potentially be a timeout. The successful query with the DISTINCT keyword executes in a few seconds - without it, it fails.

Comment: jpw - Unfortunately it doesn't provide any error messages when it fails - simply 'OBDC --Call Failed'